# VBA Split of time and date in loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of data with date and time information dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss
I am trying to loop through the column of data and get the date into col 2 and time into col 3.
The code below is happily adding the date into column 2 and in the correct number format. However, Time in col 3 is been entered as 00:00 and the format is till in dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss

Any advice would be most welcome. Thank you.

````
Dim MyLastRow As Integer
Dim MyDateTime As Date

    
   'CREATE THE LOOP START FROM THE FIRST VIABLE ROW
MyLastRow = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
 For X = 2 To MyLastRow
MyDateTime = Range("A2").Value
    'ADD ACTIONS
Cells(X + 0, 2).Value = Int(MyDateTime)
Cells(X + 0, 2).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    
Cells(X + 0, 3).Value = Int(MyDateTime)
Cells(X + 0, 3).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"

'END LOOP
Next

End Sub ```
````

Comment: replace this row Cells(X + 0, 3).Value = Int(MyDateTime) with Cells(X + 0, 3).Value = MyDateTime-Int(MyDateTime)

Answer (score 3):

In Excel, date/times are stored as a floating point number, where the integer part represents the date, and the digits after the decimal point represent the time.

For instance, with format `dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss`:

```
15/05/2020 11:23:45 = 43966.4748263889
15/05/2020 = 43966
11:23:45 = 0.4748263889
```

Your code uses the integral part for both, so it converts your date/time to the same date at time 00:00. That's your problem. Just change `Cells(X + 0, 3).Value = Int(MyDateTime)` to `Cells(X + 0, 3).Value = CDbl(MyDateTime) - Int(MyDateTime)` to keep the decimal part in time column

Fixed code:

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim MyLastRow As Integer
    Dim MyDateTime As Date
    
    'CREATE THE LOOP START FROM THE FIRST VIABLE ROW
     MyLastRow = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
     For X = 2 To MyLastRow
        MyDateTime = Range("A2").Value
        'ADD ACTIONS
        Cells(X + 0, 2).Value = Int(MyDateTime)
        Cells(X + 0, 2).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            
        Cells(X + 0, 3).Value = CDbl(MyDateTime) - Int(MyDateTime)
        Cells(X + 0, 3).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
        
        'END LOOP
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that sorted it out.

Answer (score 3):

There are native functions for exactly this task:

```vb
Cells(X + 0, 2).Value = DateValue(MyDateTime)
Cells(X + 0, 3).Value = TimeValue(MyDateTime)
```

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks!